# Changing input method on the fly

Tags: javascript, laravel, locale

I have a simple form on laravel which will take name and email only and submit it to database. Name will be in Japanese. I can validate it in controller.

However, when I am using chrome; after inserting the name in Japanese; I press TAB key and input method automatically changes when cursor is on the email field. 
But when I am using edge the input method doesn't change automatically. I have to manually change it.

Is there any way to automatically change input method on the fly regardless of the browser? Is there any JS function and/or Laravel function that I can use?

Comment: Hi Nabil. Can you post the HTML part related to your question? Also, what do you mean by the `"input method"`?

Comment: provide tab-index attribute to your input fields accordingly.

Comment: By input method I meant input language. Input language automatically changes from Japanese to English.

Comment: reset your chrome setting and you good to go..  because in your setting it's automatically converted non English to English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The trick is using css.

In the fields I need English input, I put ime-mode inactive and type = tel. 
In the fields I need Japanese input, I put ime-mode active. 
It worked. my code was something like this.

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="enter your name" style="ime-mode: active;">
<input type="tel" name="email" placeholder="enter your email" style="ime-mode: inactive;">
```